# Creating a 5x5 poylgon in ArcGIS with a predetermined center with coordinates X, Y

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, polygon-creation

I need to build a polygon (5x5 km) centered on a coordinate X,Y. I want to use this 5x5 square for an eventual clip.

How should I proceed in ArcMap?

Comment: Does it have to be a square or can it be a circle?

Comment: I need a square. I found how to center it, but I need to have a 5x5 km square and orient it North/South

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you have your center points and their XY coordinates in a table. Step 3 requires an ArcGIS Advanced license.

1. Create a point layer using your coordinates as the points. You can do this several ways, one is using the [Add XY Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) tool in ArcGIS. You just point the tool at your table of points. You'll need to specify which field is the X coordinate, which is the Y, and the coordinate system the points are in.
2. [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000) those points by 2.5 km, set the Dissolve type to NONE. That will give you a layer of circle features centered on your points, each with a diameter of 5km.
3. Use the [Feature Envelope to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000038000000) tool, using the circle layer from Step 2 as the input. That will convert the circles to squares, 5km on a side.